# Removal of adjacent duplicates by row - [R]

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame where each row represents interaction data per person.

```
actions = read.table('C:/Users/Desktop/actions.csv', header = F, sep = ',', na.strings = '', stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Each person can have one, or more of the following interactions:

```
eat, sleep, walk, jump, hop, wake, run
```

The action lengths being recorded for each person may differ as below:

```
P1: eat,  sleep, sleep, sleep
P2: wake, walk,  eat,   walk, walk, jump, jump, run, run
P3: wake, eat,   walk,  jump, run,  sleep
```

To make the lengths equal, I have NA padding at the end:

```
P1: eat,  sleep, sleep, sleep, NA,   NA,    NA,   NA,  NA
P2: wake, walk,  eat,   walk,  walk, jump,  jump, run, run
P3: wake, eat,   walk,  jump,  run,  sleep, NA,   NA,  NA
```

Now, my requirement is to update the per person entries (row wise data), so that no two consecutive entries are duplicates. It is very important to maintain the order. My required output is:

```
P1: eat,  sleep, NA,   NA,   NA,   NA,    NA,   NA,  NA
P2: wake, walk,  eat,  walk, jump, run,   NA,   NA,  NA 
P3: wake, eat,   walk, jump, run,  sleep, NA,   NA,  NA
```

The column names are by default V1, V2, V3 .... Vn where

```
n = maximum length of interactions string
```

In the above example P2 has maximum length; so n = 9. So total columns in the above example are from V1-V9.

The output for the

```
dput(actions)

structure(list(V1 = c("S", "C", "R"), V2 = c("C", "C", "R"), 
V3 = c("R", "C", "R"), V4 = c("S", NA, "R"), V5 = c("C", 
NA, "R"), V6 = c("R", NA, NA), V7 = c("S", NA, NA), V8 = c("C", 
NA, NA), V9 = c("R", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

The following question: [Removing Only Adjacent Duplicates in Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022057/removing-only-adjacent-duplicates-in-data-frame-in-r) is bit similar to mine, however, there are several differences. I am unable to solve my problem even by incorporating the code from the above question.

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Contributors: the "two consecutive" appears to be paramount.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Your solution has disappeared. It seemed to be leading me in the right direction...

Comment: it's not, though. you'll get errant results with it since it doesn't handle the "only two consecutive" properly

Comment: I think I did not convey properly:
sleep sleep sleep sleep   should result in 'sleep';
not 'sleep sleep' as I do not want duplicates.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, at least perhaps now you see that I didn't copy your solution since mine doesn't leave such duplicates.

Comment: mine didn't either @JuliusVainora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

read.csv(text=gsub(" +", "", "P1, eat,  sleep, sleep, sleep, NA,   NA,    NA,   NA,  NA
P2, wake, walk,  eat,   walk,  walk, jump,  jump, run, run
P3, wake, eat,   walk,  jump,  run,  sleep, NA,   NA,  NA"), 
           header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  setNames(c("person", sprintf("i%s", 1:9))) %>% tbl_df() -> xdf

de_dup <- function(x) {
  # remove consecutive dups and keep order
  interactions <- rle(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)[-1])$values
  # fill in NAs
  interactions <- c(interactions, rep(NA_character_, length(x[-1])-length(interactions)))
  # return a data frame
  as.data.frame(as.list(setNames(c(x[1], interactions), names(x))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

rowwise(xdf) %>% 
  do(de_dup(.)) %>% 
  ungroup()
## # A tibble: 3 x 10
##   person i1    i2    i3    i4    i5    i6    i7    i8    i9   
## * <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
## 1 P1     eat   sleep NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
## 2 P2     wake  walk  eat   walk  jump  run   NA    NA    NA   
## 3 P3     wake  eat   walk  jump  run   sleep NA    NA    NA
```

**Requested Exposition**

Since the dups are across columns, the most straightforward approach (not necessarily the fastest or least memory/CPU intensive) is to re-create the data frame row-by-row.

- `rowwise()` is a `tidyverse` function that breaks the data frame into groups by rows
- we then take each individual row (using `do()`) and pass that to a function we've created to make the code more readable and update-able (unlike confusing inline bracketed `{}` craziness with semicolons vs newlines). The `.` == the entire row
- The `x` parameter in `de_dup()` will be a named list (read the docs on `do`)
- We take that list and turn it into a vector with `unlist()`
- We then pass that into the `rle` function but not the first element which is the person. This isn't completely necessary (the person will be unique) but it has mindful logic in that you know you're working on the interactions vs the person. Look at the output of `rle(c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d))` to get an idea of what it does. It stands for run length encoding and it is purpose built for needs like yours
- The return value of `rle` has a `values` element which has the de-duped elements without `NA`s.
- Due to ^^ we have to re-pad the `NA`s again. Lots of ways to do this. I like this way.
- We then have to return a data frame (check the docs on `do()` again) so we create a named character vector and turn it into a data frame
- At the end of `do()` we still have a row-by-row grouped data frame so we then need to ungroup it

Comment: didn't see the "V" note in your edited question before finishing

Comment: Thanks, the solution is mostly working and it is amazing!!
Just a little trouble, i think if there are more than 3 or more duplicate entries in a row; the code produces 2 instances in the output.

An entry which had

    'sleep sleep sleep    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA '

was reduced to 

    'sleep sleep NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA'

And in another case, 

'walk walk walk walk walk NA NA NA NA'

came down to 

'walk walk NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA'

Comment: Oh. So the "two consecutive" is paramount. i.e. it's not just "all consecutive"?

Comment: Thanks!
Your code works fine except at the first occurrence at the start of a line.

Comment: lemme poke at that. i thought that might be an edge case

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way using base R. I have simply created a function that will replace consecutive duplicates with `NA` and rearrange the new row in desired order -

```
# function to check consecutive duplicates
ccd <- function(x) {
  # first value can never be duplicate so initiating to 0
  test <- c(0, sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i) anyDuplicated(x[i:(i+1)])))
  x[test > 0] <- NA_character_
  x[order(test)]
}

# Original df from dput
> df
  V1 V2 V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9
1  S  C  R    S    C    R    S    C    R
2  C  C  C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  R  R  R    R    R <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[r, ] <- ccd(as.character(df[r, ]))
}

> df
  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9
1  S    C    R    S    C    R    S    C    R
2  C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  R <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

---

For the demo-ed example in post -

```
df <- read.csv(
text=gsub(" +", "", "P1, eat,  sleep, sleep, sleep, NA,   NA,    NA,   NA,  NA
P2, wake, walk,  eat,   walk,  walk, jump,  jump, run, run
                         P3, wake, eat,   walk,  jump,  run,  sleep, NA,   NA,  NA"), 
               header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[, -1]

> df
    V2    V3    V4    V5   V6    V7   V8   V9  V10
1  eat sleep sleep sleep <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 wake  walk   eat  walk walk  jump jump  run  run
3 wake   eat  walk  jump  run sleep <NA> <NA> <NA>

for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[r, ] <- ccd(as.character(df[r, ]))
}

> df
    V2    V3   V4   V5   V6    V7   V8   V9  V10
1  eat sleep <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 wake  walk  eat walk jump   run <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 wake   eat walk jump  run sleep <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `dplyr`, `reshape2` and base R. First, it identifies the desired duplicates and replace them with NA. Then, it shifts the non-NA values to the left.

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df %>%
          gather(var, val, -V1) %>% 
          group_by(V1) %>% 
          mutate(val2 = ifelse(val == lag(val), NA, val),
                 val2 = ifelse(var == "V2", paste(val), val2)) %>% 
          dcast(V1~var, value.var = "val2"), 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))))

  V1   V2    V3   V4   V5   V6    V7   V8   V9  V10
1 P1  eat sleep <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 P2 wake  walk  eat walk jump   run <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 P3 wake   eat walk jump  run sleep <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Data (using the code from @Shree):

```
df <- read.csv(text = gsub(" +", "", "P1, eat,  sleep, sleep, sleep, NA,   NA,    NA,   NA,  NA
            P2, wake, walk,  eat,   walk,  walk, jump,  jump, run, run
            P3, wake, eat,   walk,  jump,  run,  sleep, NA,   NA,  NA"), 
               header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```