# What's the best way to delete successive duplicate row

Tags: r

How to remove successive duplicate rows based on first column`v1`?

```
v1  v2
1   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
1   A
1   A
2   A
2   B
```

*Desired Output:*

```
v1 v2
1  A
2  B
3  B
1  A
2  A
```

Comment: df[cumsum(rle(df$v1)$lengths),]

Comment: `d[c(1, diff(d$v1)) != 0,]`

Comment: @AnkurSinha Duplicate of [Removing Only Adjacent Duplicates in Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022057/removing-only-adjacent-duplicates-in-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `rle` in base R -

```
x <- c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,2)

ind <- with(rle(x), sequence(lengths) == 1)

x[ind]

[1] 1 2 3 1 2
```

Another way would be by checking lag values -

```
ind <- c(TRUE, x[-length(x)] != x[-1])

x[ind]

[1] 1 2 3 1 2
```